# HSQL 2.3.6 outer join syntax

Tags: sql, join, hsqldb, outer-join

I use **HSQL 2.3.6** and I want to make a join with the following syntax :

```
SELECT A.REF FROM TableA A, TableB B
WHERE A.NUM = B.NUM (+)
```

But in the documentation (most recent of my version of HSQL) http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_joined_table the syntax it's :

```
<joined table> ::= <cross join> | <qualified join> | <natural join>

<qualified join> ::= <table reference> | [ <join type> ] JOIN <table reference> <join specification>

<join specification> ::= <join condition> | <named columns join>

<join condition> ::= ON <search condition>

<join type> ::= INNER | <outer join type> [ OUTER ]

<outer join type> ::= LEFT | RIGHT | FULL

<join column list> ::= <column name list>
```

With my syntax I have `SQLSyntaxErrorException`, and I think it's because my syntax is not compatible.

But not having the documentation for my HSQL's version, I'm not sure. You confirmed ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the `2.0` manual actually means `2.x`

Comment: HSQLDB version 2.3.6 is the JDK 6 compatible version for HSQLDB 2.4.1. There is no change in existing SQL syntax in later versions. You can download the 2.4.1 docs here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/hsqldb/files/hsqldb/

Comment: The `(+)` is a remnant from Oracle in the 80's, when SQL-92 didn't exist yet. Avoid that old syntax, since it has many limitations and doesn't work anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(+)` is Oracle's proprietary operator for outer joins (which is only supported by Oracle), and even Oracle recommends to stop using it.

HSQLDB supports the standard LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA A
  LEFT JOIN TableB B on A.NUM = B.NUM;
```

(not sure I got the direction right, I haven't used Oracle's `(+)` operator for decades)

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You are using archaic, bespoke syntax for an outer join.  I think you want:

```
SELECT A.REF
FROM TableA A LEFT JOIN
     TableB B
     ON A.NUM = B.NUM;
```

You have probably oversimplified your query.  As written, there is probably no need for the outer join:

```
SELECT A.REF
FROM TableA A ;
```